# iOS push notifications work different in different application states

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I send 10 messages in row to APNS.When application is in background, I receive all of them.
But when Application is in foreground I recieve 8 notifications.

What can be a problem here?

Here is my code which is extremely  simple:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    NSLog(@"Test push...");
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone)];
    [self checkForRegisteredUser];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure will this is what you're looking for,

Here is how push notification works,

So when you application is on background, you application will never receive the push notification from the APNs but it will come to your notification tray with the message as they sent it from the server.

But if your application is in the foreground. the method in you app delegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
```

will receive the notification and will perform the necessary action as you have defined in it.

In case if you did not receive the notification you need to check the network connection.

I have developed a similar application like yours and its works well as you are expecting..

Comment: That is problem.My app is in foreground,but method didReceiveRemoteNotification: is not executed every time.For example if I send 10 push notifications, 8 are received and other are not recieved.Where can be a issue?